# What's happening when $V = I$ ($R$ equals one)?

Tags: electricity, charge, electrical-resistance, voltage

If a circuit has a resistance of 1 ohm, and the potential difference = current, are the charges flowing at the same rate as they are losing potential energy or something? If yes, what does that mean? If not, what is happening?

(Sorry if I don't make complete sense, correct me if I'm wrong on anything.)

Comment: I didn't d/v but I kinda think you are pushing the envelope here on lack of research :), you need a more precise question.

Comment: what’s so special about $1\Omega$ that you can’t take the answer for any resistance and apply it to this case?  (agreed that the d/v is a bit quick, although the question ought to be revised and clarified.)

Comment: Nothing special about 1 $\Omega$; in cgs electrostatic units (with statvolts etc) it would have a different value.

Comment: Potential difference is never equal to current, even when the resistance is exactly 1 ohm, any more than distance is equal to time when you're travelling at 1 mile per hour.

Comment: @Countto10 What does d/v mean?

Comment: Downvote, sorry for the abbreviation.

Comment: What @Philip means to say is that, while the _magnitude_ of $V$ and $I$ may be the same, the unit attached to $R$ ($\Omega$ or $\frac {kg⋅m^2} {s^3⋅A^3}$ in base SI units) changes the unit attached to $I$ into that attached to $V$

Answer (score 3):

There is no deeper meaning behind because there is nothing particular with that value. It is not any special value. The resistance could be bigger or smaller and the circuit would behave QUALITATIVELY similarly.

The fact that you get $1\Omega$ in your example is, after all, just a matter of how we have decided the unit system. We the humans have decided to measure voltage in Volts and Intensity in amperes, so that resistance is in ohms. If we had chosen another definition for the "intensity unit", then it wouldn't be amperes anymore but another one. The resistance would have a different value, but the meaning would be the same. So the numerical value doesn't tell you too much unless you've got something else.

The numerical value is important when it is zero, infinite, or any other special case (minima, maxima...). Otherwise it's just a datus that depends on the units.

The numerical value, consequently, has only meaning when either you NEED a certain concrete value in your device, or you've got some other values to compare with. If that's not the case, 1 Ohm can be big, small, or whatever you want. You need a reference to compare.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I believe there is no deeper meaning beyond what you've specified in the situation. These two quantities are most directly linked by [Ohm's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law). Its intuitive application may answer your question; for this scenario, it simply says that what you have a potential difference of $1V$ across a piece of material when $1A$ flows through it, then that piece of material has a resistance of $1\Omega$. What it means to have a potential difference of $1V$ or a current of $1A$ have their own definitions in separate contexts.

Answer (score -1):

To add on to Billy's answer, there is no deeper meaning because $R$ is not dimensionless. Let's take $R = 1\Omega$ for the rest of the answer.

Let upright letters denote numerical values of the corresponding quantity in italics, in the specified system of units.

In volts and amperes then, 
$$
R = 1 \mathrm{\ volt/ampere}
$$

and thus

$$
\begin{align}
V &= IR \\
\implies \mathrm{V} &= \mathrm{I}
\end{align}
$$

If I write $V$ in millivolts and $I$ in amperes, however,

$$
R = 1000 \mathrm{\ millivolt/ampere}
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}
V &= IR \\
\implies \mathrm{V} &= 1000*\mathrm{I}
\end{align}
$$

For a particular value of $R$, any relation between the numerical value of $V$ and $I$ in a system of units might not hold in another system of units, since $R$ is not a dimensionless ratio of $V$ and $I$.

Comment: Your equations are dimensionally inconsistent. *Regardless of what you choose to measure voltage, current and resistance in*, the equation is always $V = RI$. You write that $R$ is not dimensionless, but then have no trouble writing $R=1$ - please make the answer less confused on that point.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thanks for pointing that out. I suppose the answer is okay now?

Comment: No, the equations $V=I$ and $V=1000\cdot I$ are still dimensionally incorrect.

Comment: I clarified in the answer, the upright symbols $\mathrm{V}$ and $\mathrm{I}$ are **not** physical quantities, they are numerical values of the voltage and current respectively in the chosen system of units.

Comment: So if $V = 1 \mathrm{\ volt}$ then in volts, $\mathrm{V} = 1$ and in millivolts, $\mathrm{V} = 1000$. I'm abusing notation a little by using the same symbol for both (dimensionless) numbers, admittedly.